# How to delete user account from admin account in listview in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

I've created code to delete user. I create admin function that can delete the user. I'have created the coding but then I realized that user account only got deleted at the user database but not the authentication? How to delete the user database with their authentication at Firebase?

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int i) {

        myViewHolder.email.setText(custList.get(i).getEmail());
        myViewHolder.name.setText(custList.get(i).getName());
        myViewHolder.telephone_number.setText(custList.get(i).getTelephone_number());


        myViewHolder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String email = custList.get(i).getEmail();
                String id = custList.get(i).getId();

                DatabaseReference dbCust = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Customer");
                dbCust.child(id).removeValue();

                //Toolbar
                // Remove the item on remove/button click
                custList.remove(i);
                /*
                    Parameters
                        position : Position of the item that has now been removed
                */
                notifyItemRemoved(i);

                /*
                    Parameters
                        positionStart : Position of the first item that has changed
                        itemCount : Number of items that have changed
                */
                notifyItemRangeChanged(i, custList.size());

                // Show the removed item label
                Toast.makeText(context, email + " has been removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only delete a user if he/she is logged in from Android using [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#delete_a_user).

But if you want to delete any user either logged in or not, you have to use [Admin Sdk](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users).

In my opinion, the easiest way would be, to use Cloud Functions with Admin Sdk. It can listen to database changes. When you see a delete operation on user, you can delete that user from authentication. For example, see [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#perform_sanitization_and_maintenance)

Comment: FirebaseAuth.getInstance().deleteUser(uid);
System.out.println("Successfully deleted user."); Do i have to add this coding inside my adapter class?

Comment: @lylyn right after `notifyItemRemoved(i);`would be ok

Comment: how do i modified my coding to add the coding, it seems like i got error at deleteUser(uid)

Comment: from android, you can only delete yourself as user, if your are logged in, but not any other users.